# adb backup that operates similar to dd

Tags: backup, adb

Do adb backup methods contain those that operate similar to how dd backups data? So I want to know if adb backup method that hard-copies every bit of disk exists.

If it does not exist, is there any way to do things similar to what dd does?

Comment: It'd be easier to judge what method is most appropriate if you would add to your question some information about why you want something like `dd`. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

`dd` is a block-based copy tool -- it doesn't care what data it covers. `adb backup` is rather file-based, which is something completely different.

As you've tagged your question [backup](/questions/tagged/backup), you might follow that tag to [its tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/backup/info), which gives you some insight into available backup methods. You will quickly see the one coming closest to `dd` being Nandroid, which copies entire partitions. Though you cannot restrict it in the way you can with `dd`, you could still take its resulting files, copy them to your Linux computer, and use `dd` to work on them.

One tool not mentioned in this tag-wiki is `dd` itself. You could check with a terminal editor whether it's present on your device -- chances are good: I just checked with one of my extracted Nandroid backups, and found `dd` as a symlink in `/system/bin`, being a symlink to `/system/toolbox`. If you cannot find it, but your device is rooted (which I assume, as otherwise `dd` wouldn't make much sense), you could look for a BusyBox which brings it along.